# split string with "."

Tags: perl, split

I am trying to split a string with `"."` but getting nothing in the array. File name is `"Head-First-Java-2nd-edition.pdf"` After splitting I want to extract extension, but don't know why it is giving blank array.

```
my @fileInfo = split(/./, $filename);
 &logMsg("Array is: @fileInfo");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The split is giving an empty list because you are splitting on a wildcard `.`. Period is a meta character, and if you want to split on a literal period, you need to escape it

```
my @fileInfo = split(/\./, $filename);
```

Also, the syntax for calling a subroutine is `NAME(LIST)`. Using the `&` prefix has a certain hidden feature, in that it circumvents prototypes. Read more in [perldoc perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html).

Comment: Thank a lot.Working now :)

Answer (score 2):

`.` in a regular expression means any character except `\n`. To split on a literal `.`, you need to escape it:

```
split /\./, $filename;
```